# how to display only texture (100%in color) in evee viewport ? 2.8

Tags: 3d-view

I need to see the texture in 100% color without any lightning on the model. How can to disable all the lightning so the model is displayed only textured? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found another way:

In the upper right of your 3D viewport are settings for the viewport shading method. Select the white sphere (Solid mode) and then choose Flat and Texture.